# How do I specify a build entrypoint via command line?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a webpack config like this:

```
module.exports = [
    {
     name: 'build1',
     entry: './src/mebuild.ts'
     output: {
         filename: 'bundle.js'
     }
    },
    {
     name: 'build2',
     entry: './src/mebuild2.ts'
     output: {
         filename: 'bundle2.js'
     }
    }
]
```

When I run `webpack` the project builds fine. However, it builds both entrypoints and copies both built bundle files to the output folder. Is there a way I can specify a specific one at build time? Something like this would be ideal:

```
webpack --name build1
```

But the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/) dont have any information on this. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for `webpack.config.js` to export a function that you can pass parameters into from the command line.

Passing parameters from the command line:

```
webpack --env.name=build1
```

This will pass an object to `webpack.config.js`:

```
{ name: 'build1' }
```

Then in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = env => {
  const { name } = env;

  return {
    // Rest of config utilizing name
  };
};
```

This process was described by Sean Larkin in the Web Fundamentals course he created on https://webpack.academy. You need to create an account to view it, but it's all free.